# create sql table in SQLServer with the name of the current session variable c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005, session

I am developing an application in c #. Net and I need to create a table in sql with the name of the current session variable.
How I can send the value of the session variable to current sql server to create this query?
My idea is something like this:
In sql server:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_ + 'current user name' // current session variable in c#
(First_Name char(50),
Last_Name char(50),
Address char(50),
City char(50),
Country char(25),
Birth_Date datetime);
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: are you sure you want to make a table for every customer?

Comment: Yes, in fact the name of the table would "result_ + 'current user name'".
This table contains standardized address records. In my web application I can have 2 users simultaneously normalizing their records, then I need to differentiate the result of normalization for each user to download their own standardized records.
If you have a better idea would be great and I really appreciate it!

Comment: I think it's a bad design to do so. If i understand you correctly, you could use XML data type. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403385.aspx

Comment: Thanks for responding, I will study what you indicate

Comment: A better idea would be to have a single table which includes a column to stores the user id or the session variable.

Comment: I have store user id and session variable. But my problem is differentiate the created table, which contains different data, the data that the user has loaded, so that after this process the user can download the data normalized

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating a query in c# as a string and sending via sqlcommand? If so, just use

```
System.Environment.UserName
```

Comment: something. In a button_click (which is the normalized records) to send the value of the session variable to the query for use in the name of the table.